# What code do I need to fix Apache HTTP Client removal?

Tags: android, apache, email, http

Android 6.0 Marshmallow Version 23.0 broke my code
Running Android Studio 1.5.1.

Caused by Apache HTTP Client removal

developer.android.com Android 6.0 Changes says use HttpURLConnection class instead.

```
package ...

import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP; // here is my error -- Cannot resolve symbol 'HTTP'

class ...   

    Intent emailIntent;

    void share() { // put the data in a blank gmail that the user can send -- they choose the recipients
        emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE); // here is my error -- Cannot resolve symbol 'HTTP'
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""}); // recipients
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ShareSubject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, idList.getText() + "\n" + defList.getText() + "\n");
        startActivityForResult(emailIntent, 1);
    }

} // Class
```

The above code was working on Android 5 Version 22.0
I replaced import apache with:

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
but Android Studio shows this line is unused.

I searched android developer under HttpURLConnection and found nothing under email or share.
I searched apache for `HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE` and got deprecated (which I am painfully aware of).
I see code "How To Make HTTP POST Request To Server" but not how to populate an email.
I suspect I have to post to the gmail "Server" but I don't know how.
I comment out the errant line: `emailIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);`
And get the following error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND flg=0x1 (has clip) (has extras)

This email share is the same function you use when you are viewing some code on your phone and want to share it.
You click the menu then "share" and it populates a gmail that you can send (typically to yourself back on the desktop).
Could you please share the code I am missing that will run under Android 6?

Comment: I was just about to write an answer about `android { useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' }` but what do you want to do? Sending E-Mails with the http library!?

Comment: I looked at legacy but I couldn't make it run. I want to populate the subject matter and body of an email (gmail) and bring it up for the user to add the recipient(s) and send it.

Comment: But sending mails has nothing to do with the http library... oh you use `org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE`... I have a better idea... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a little until I understood your problem. I checked the full source code of the SDK, it is true there is no other constant you could use. However the string you are searching for is `"text/plain"`. You can insert it directly.

However I would suggest to use another code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                                Uri.fromParts("mailto", "you@example.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, /*...*/);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, /*...*/);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, /*...*/);
startActivityForResult(emailIntent, 1);
```

This intent will just open real mail clients.