# PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE issue

Tags: android

I am having and issue with the line "emailIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);" as it says cannot resolve issue for the PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE part. I am working through this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html
and kept the code the same.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setType takes a String so you can circumvent it (as it says in the comment) by doing this:

```
 emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

---

I did a quick Google, looks like the docs made sense for Android v5 but not since then :-) aka above Marshmallow. `HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE` is apart of apache http which used to be bundled with Android. [What code do I need to fix Apache HTTP Client removal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34457924/413127)
TLDR just use the String as above.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client

---

Raised a bug for them to fix the docs: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148429148 :-)